# What's a smart approach to parsing "forum-style" tags within a string of random HTML?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, html-parsing

So I'm working with some pretty awesome HTML strings stored in our DB and I need to be able to parse out the string between the "forum-style" youtube tags as in the example below. I have a solution, but it feels a bit hackish. I'm thinking there's probably a more elegant way to handle this problem.

```
<?php

    $video_string = '<p><span style="font-size: 12px;"><span style="font-family: verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">[youtube]KbI_7IHAsyw[/youtube]<br /></span></span></p>';

    $matches = array();
    preg_match('/\][_A-Za-z0-9]+\[/', $video_string, $matches);

    $yt_vid_key = substr($matches[0], 1, strlen($matches[0]) - 2 );
```

Comment: Nitpick: This aren't "forum"-style tags. These are "bulletin board"-"tags".

Comment: @mario Pretty nitpicky indeed, bro. Not that I should expect anything less from a fellow coder. We are a pedantic bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd change the regex a bit:

```
    '/\[youtube\](.*?)\[\/youtube\]/is'
```

Adding the 'youtube' part to not replace ALL bb-codes - only the right ones.
I've also added the '?' to make the regex less greedy (incase there are multiple YT videos in one post.
I added the pattern modifiers i and s, to be able to match case-insensitive and multiline strings.

Edit:
You may also rather want to use preg_replace, it'll be a bit less code that way.

Comment: This is great. So apparently the parens set up a new grouping?

Comment: Yes, its especially useful, since you can access the bit that got matched by the paranthesis with '$1' in your substitute string! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 preg_match('!\[youtube\]([_A-Za-z0-9]+?)\[/youtube\]!',$subject, $matches);

 $yt_vid_key = $matches[1];
```

if you expect multiple occurances, use `preg_match_all` instead.

Comment: This answer is nice too. I went with the answer from @Kisaro because it seems bit more robust.

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers provided here are correct if you don't expect nested tags if so then you have to come up with a way to match the tags properly, which can't really be done in regex and you will have to create some sort of way to handle it.

Here is some pseudo like code to help you out

```
find opening tag to tag match

openTags = 0
closeTags = 0
position = 0

do{
    Move through the string: increase position
    if open tag matches: openTags++
    if close tag matches: closeTags++, positionOfCloseTag = position
}while(openTags > closeTags);

first occurence of close tag after the last close tag you found in do-while loop is the correct matching of the tag.
```